# Why to obtain the coordinates of vectors in the basis that themselves belong?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $ \space T: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ a linear transformation defined as $ \space T(x,y)=(3x+2y,x+y,-2x-y)$, where $\beta=\{(1,-1),(0,1)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Is not specify a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$.

By the expression of $ \space T(x,y)$ one known that,

$$T(1,-1)=(1,0,-1)$$
$$T(0,1)=(2,1,-1)$$

The matrix will have $3$ lines by $2$ columns. Since there wasn't a specific basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$ I assumed the canonic basis. So the linear combination of each $T(1,-1)$ and $T(0,1)$ in the canonic $\mathbb{R^3}$ basis are themselves.

The matrix will be,

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$

But,

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}\neq$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$

My doubt is, why it's need to write each vector of $\beta$ as a linear combination of themselves to get their coordinates in the basis that they belong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that $(1,-1)$ is the first vector of $\beta$ it has coordinates $(1,0)$.

When you use matrices to apply the linear transformation you are using the coordinates of the vector on a fixed basis.

So you should write $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0& 1\\ -1 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

If $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis and $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_iv_i$ then you can say that the coordinates of $v$ **on this basis** is $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$.

So what is the coordinate of $v_i$ on this basis? That is $(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{i-1},1,0,\ldots,0)$.

Comment: Isn't the transformation matrix derived from the given transformation T(x)?

Answer (score 1):

When you consider $ \{ (1,-1),(0,1)\}$ as a base for the domain of $T$ and then you get  $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0& 1\\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$ then $(1,-1)=1(1,-1)+0(1,0)$ and so :

$$T(1,-1)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0& 1\\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=(1,0,-1)$$